# Android merging videos by frames

Tags: android, video, merge, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to develop video merge application in android. I am able to merge two videos but if the video size is more the device gets hanged .So I want to get frames of input video2(around 15 sec.) and merge it to video1. Any one have an idea how to get the frames from video. Is there direct native method available for that to get frames?.

Comment: What's wrong with ffmpeg?

Comment: can we merge frame by frame in ffmpeg

Comment: What do you mean by merge frame by frame? If you want one video to appear in the end of another, that's **concatenating**. If you want two video to be shown at the same moment with one layering on top of another using an opacity, that's **blending**. If you want your video frame sequence to be something like [1st frame of A, 1st frame of B, 2nd frame of A, 2nd frame of B, 3rd frame of A, 3rd frame of B], the video seems to be flashing between the two videos, this should be **intersecting**.

Comment: Of course, if you just want a method to get decoded frames of video and do everything else your self. I recommend you OpenCV built with ffmpeg as video backend.

Comment: i want to concatenate two videos

Comment: Then newer builds of ffmpeg version could do the job. see this link: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files , I would build ffmpeg into a binary executable and use it in android with Runtime.exec instead of JNI. You can put the built executable in your assets and copy it into your app private storage path and make it executable.

Comment: This could also be done with `MediaCodec` on API 18+; see http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest .  The ffmpeg approach looks like less work, but I don't know if it's taking advantage of the hardware codecs.  I'm also curious to know what the previous approach was, and what "the device gets hanged" means.